# Combine two users

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

When I have joined Mathematica.SE, I unfortunatly logged in into two computers, and couldnt remember my other username, so I created two of them. This one and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/14578/mario).

Is there any way to combine these two users?

Thank you!

Comment: Your credentials are different for both accounts. Login with the same credentials and it'll be automatically merged. You can also email the SE team here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @rm-rf I thought this was a question about [user21](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18437/user21) 囧.

Comment: @xzczd Well, obviously it's not...